# Why does this combination correspond to an injection from $\mathbb{N_2} \rightarrow Y$?

Tags: combinatorics, functions, combinations

Suppose 3 people each select a main dish from a menu of five items. How many distinct choices are possible if 2 people select the same dish?

The solution:

Let $X$ be the set of 3 people and $Y$ be the set of 5 dishes.

If only two distinct dishes are selected then one must be selected once and the other twice so that the possibilities correspond to injections $\mathbb{N_2} \rightarrow Y$ and so the number of distinct choices is $|\text{Inj}(\mathbb{N}_2,Y)|=20$

I don't understand why the type of choices we need to compute corresponds to injections  $\mathbb{N_2} \rightarrow Y$. I tried drawing some diagrams but still don't get it.

My answer was:

A choice corresponds to an order from the 3 customers.

There are ${5 \choose 2}=10$ ways to select two dishes from a set of 5 dishes. For each of the 10 selections, the 3rd dish must be either one of the two in the given selection. Therefore, each of the 10 selections corresponds to 2 orders, so the total orders where 2 dishes are the same is $10 \times 2 = 20$

I got the same answer but I am not sure if my method is equivalent to the provided solution or it is just a coincidence that I arrived at the same answer. In any case, I still don't see how this is equivalent to an injection.

Comment: Notice that they are ignoring which people order which dish; they only care about the dishes being selected.

Comment: What's $\mathbb{N}_2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to select two distinct dishes, so an injection $f:\mathbb{N}_2 \rightarrow Y$ picks out these two dishes, $f(0)$ and $f(1)$.  The injection forces us to pick two $\textit{distinct}$ dishes, and the fact that the two maps $f(0)=x,f(1)=y$ and $f(0)=y,f(1)=x$ give two different injections corresponds to the multiplication by 2 in your solution.  Counting these injections is actually exactly the same as your solution.  You can also think of the injection as keeping track of which meal was ordered twice; say $f(0)$ was the meal ordered twice and $f(1)$ was the meal ordered once.